# Is it a good idea to sync a database every half a second?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc

I have a spring boot application that gets data in database every 500μs using @Scheduled. A friend of mine discouraged me saying its a malpractice. Here is my sample code:

```
   @Scheduled(fixedRate = 500)
    @Override
    public void sync() {
        departments.setAll((Collection<? extends Department>) departmentRepository.findAll());
        sections.setAll((Collection<? extends Section>) sectionRepository.findAll());
        positions.setAll((Collection<? extends Position>) positionRepository.findAll());
    }
```

My application is working fine but my only worry is weather it's a good practice? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: I see no pros. Only cons. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @BoristheSpider The reason for doing this is that when a user on computer A updates or adds an item, a user on computer B should be able to get the updates.

Comment: If both users are hitting the same database then there should be no need to explicitly "sync" the data for each user. BTW, you meant 500ms, not 500μs, right?

Comment: @GordThompson yes 500ms. But that means user on computer B will need to refresh to get the updates

Comment: Yes, the application will have to pull an updated list of Departments, etc. *whenever it needs one*. No need for a background task to force a complete refresh of *all* lists 120 times per minute.

Comment: @GordThompson thanks for that but how can I get an update only when a user has saved a record without using schedules?

Comment: You're trying to write a push based system based on a non-push backend. So either 1) work around this limitation or 2) change the backend. The first solution would require another notification channel, for example a write-through cache or perhaps Gossip. The second solution would require changing the database to one that supports push notifications on change.

Comment: Have you looked at [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/)? I would rather recommend a publish/subscribe mechanismn to notify the remote machine about changes.

Comment: @Glains this is **not** a Kafka problem? What would the durability be for? I really wish people would stop suggesting the Cool New Thing for every problem.

Comment: RabbitMQ can be used for pub/sub model, where Computer B subscribes to a topic. Computer A will publish an DataUpdatedEvent as and when new data arrives. Optionally the delta can be transmitted over the RabbitMQ itself, so sync job may not be required at all. https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html
It really depends on lot of factors: frequency of change, volume of change, etc.

Comment: Guys I appreciate all your comments. I'll try using event triggers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very Bad Practice,

You need to find another way for your users to see the updates rather than doing this, if no updates came for 30 minutes, your database will keep syncing, better if you try to use something like Triggers.